# can someone interpert max_input_time directive for me?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I am having a real problem understanding this.  max_input_time = This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST, GET and file uploads.

So this is the time it will wait to receive data i assume.

Then i ask my self, if that is its purpose would it serve if you never know what file size the person may upload or what his upload speed really is.

So my second assumption would be, the time it takes to copy it to the temporary directory. Which is a more logical explanation.

Does any one know for sure or has tested?

Answer (score 1):

> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST, GET and file uploads.

I have *not* tested myself, but my common sense interpretation of this, of which I am 99% sure it is correct, is:

The time *after* Apache has received the request, and *before* the PHP script starts. The time it takes for PHP to break up the request data, copy any received files into the temporary directory, and presumably, also to populate the `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables that are available in the PHP script.

This means that the client's upload speed is not relevant for `max_input_time`, but the uploaded file's size can be.

Comment: dude.. the only reason im even questioning this, is because i found one of your posts that was stating this. but not one person i speak it can confirm this and insists its simply the upload time.. time it takes to upload a file.  :(

Comment: @john I'm fairly sure this is not the case, because *Apache* is the instance receiving the request. Only when the request is completely received, it is passed on to PHP. Therefore, I can't see how PHP can have control over the reception process. But fair enough - interested to see whether any definite information manages to come up.

Comment: then why is the manual providing such a vauge  description? and how come no one else points this out. Im not doubting your answer. I just want ot know why?

Comment: @john good question! I can't tell anything more from the PHP source code, but that's no wonder because I don't really know my way around it.  Maybe it's worth opening a bug report about the vague description and seeing what happens - I may do that later if I get around to it.

Comment: @john I filed a bug, we'll see whether anything comes from it. http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53590&

Comment: i will test that it out for my self i guess. What about post_max_size and upload_max_filesize   i assume that upload_max is a setting for one or many files that are being uploaded as a sum .. and  post_max  is  all those files + overhead..  now what could be considered overhead? i want to know how much extra to set it to?

Comment: @John I don't know how large the overhead is. Btw, there's an interesting new comment in the bug report

Comment: I have just read the comment but i guess i don't know how to interpret it properly. Does that prove your  theory of how it works? And also he talks about something else i dont understand.   I dont suppose i can ask you to break it down for me in simple english?  Thanks alot for all your help

Comment: @john if I read it correctly, it indeed refers to the time after the request has been received and before the script is run, *but* some of the global variables are parsed *on demand* (That's how I interpret his "just in time") so some of the parsing will take place after the script has started running, so parsing time will also be counting towards max_execution_time. But the time seems in no case to refer to the time before PHP starts (= the upload process)

Comment: so the verdict is  max_input_time != take it takes to upload but rather take it takes AFTER upload and before the max_execution_time. Confirmed?

Comment: @john as far as I can see, and the commenter (who seems to be a member of the PHP team) says, yes.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, to get to the bottom of this. You're the man !!!!

Comment: @john you're welcome. As you pointed out I answered this before but never with hard data, which we now (kind of) have, which is nice.

Comment: +1 Definitely should be accepted answer. I'm glad I learned this little gem: "parsing is actually deferred until script execution time, when the variable's requested." I didn't know that!